# Keyboard Shortcut To Send Text Strings To Program

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, text, macro

How can I configure a shortcut key to send a text string to the current program?

The purpose is to type common entries quicker (email address, street address, phone number, username, favorite quote, etc).

I don't need any further automation than just entering the text.

Gentoo Linux (3.2.12-gentoo)
Xfce Desktop Environment (Version 4.8)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One simple approach is [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml), like

```
xdotool type 'text'
```

Comment: That's half the solution... how do I assign a keyboard shortcut to run that?  Making a shortcut in Xfce 4.8 Settings, Keyboard didn't work.

Comment: @Steven Does it work directly from a terminal?

Comment: Yes.  Also, 'sleep 5 && xdotool type text' sends the text to the "active" window.

Comment: @Steven I haven't used Xfce in a while, but my next hunch is that when the command is run, the active window is wrong somehow.  I'd try running `xdotool getwindowfocus` both from a terminal and as a keyboard shortcut while the same terminal is open and compare the results for equality.  You'll probably have to redirect the keyboard shortcut version to a temporary file in order to see it.

Comment: I use `xbindkeys`.

Comment: Combining all of the above with `xvkbd` worked for me.  `xbindkeys` for the keyboard shortcut and `xvkbd` for the typing.  Adding a brief sleep was also required, so the final `.xindkeysrc` command looks like `"sleep 0.1 && xvkbd -text me@howdy"`  This substitutes for textexpander for macos on linux

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 7):

The xdotool works. 
However if you integrate it with the keyboard shortcut .. a simple xdotool type 'text' fails.

THe following shell script helped me in that

```
windowid=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
sleep 0.5 && xdotool windowactivate --sync $windowid type 'text'
```

Comment: The manuals for `xdotool` show that it has an internal sleep. `xdotool sleep 0.3 type 'Emotional 2003'` suffices. (The short sleep is necessary for some reason, I don’t know. It seems like there is a short switch of the activated or focused window when running a command?)

Answer (score 5):

You may use [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). Here is the description from the web site. “AutoKey is a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11. It allows you to manage collection of scripts and phrases, and assign abbreviations and hotkeys to these. This allows you to execute a script or insert text on demand in whatever program you are using.”

It is packaged, as far as I can tell, for Gentoo (announced [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-799638-start-0.html)); for Ubuntu ([here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/autokey-gtk/)); Debian ([here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=autokey))...

Answer (score 2):

One-liner that worked for me (stolen from the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393164/207995) by k.tsm)

```
xdotool sleep 0.3 type 'string that you want to type / paste'
```

Then assign a shortcut to this command in KDE and after your pressing the shortcut, the required text is magically typed for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to control open file dialog input in linux  :

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess , time

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'o' , interval = 0.15)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'l' , interval = 0.15)
subprocess.Popen("xdotool sleep 0.3 type  '{Path_file}'".format(Path_file = "............................") , shell = True)
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```