# How to quickly add some space in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, console, whitespace

I often find myself scrolling back through the terminal with the mouse-wheel to see the first of many C++ template errors issued by a command. Anticipating this, I'll hold down the <kbd>Return</kbd> key to give some space from previous outputs; to allow me to more easily read off the first error. I find this preferable to piping into `head -n` as then I have to estimate `n`. Similarly, the `clear` command only clears the terminal screen.

Is there anything faster than holding down <kbd>Return</kbd> like this? I've seen solutions appropriate for scripting (echo loops; jot; yes/head), but was wondering if there's a short command I'm unaware of.

Comment: what about `reset`

Comment: @Lambert `reset` removes the visual history, I'd like that to remain.

Comment: @mikeserv That `yes` invocation needs terminating; and will quickly give far more space than I want.

Comment: Then how about: `alias space='for lines in {1..10}; do echo; done'`. Then call `space` from the terminal to get 10 blank lines.

Comment: @mikeserv Have you seen how fast `yes` issues space? And yes, I know CTRL+C, but no I don't want to use it; I'm looking for something fast. The `clear` command does its job, but so does `tput clear`. The `clear` developers, and many others care about brevity; so do I.

Comment: @Lambert I think something like this will have to do. I use lots of machines; my hope was that this may exist already.

Comment: @mikeserv Not bad, though a little verbose. Also needs tuning to the width of the terminal.

Comment: That's pretty nice @mikeserv. So: `printf` `CTRL-L`.

Comment: No - just type CTRL+L together.

Comment: Ah yes, that's perfect!

Comment: Key-bindings in `bash`: `bind '"\e[24~":"\n\n\n\n\n"'` and press F12.

Comment: @mikeserv, using `vi`-mode here for line input, I need Esc Ctrl+L

Comment: @roaima - In `vi` mode you can tie the contents of a shell alias named *`_letter`* to *`<ESC>@letter`*.

Comment: @mikeserv, I would use `bind -m vi-insert '"\C-l": clear-screen'`, but Ctrl/L isn't really on my list of things I use much

Comment: @roaima - I didn't mean it would *run* the shell alias, necessarily. It doesn't get run as a command, exactly, but it interprets it as input. So you could have `alias _l=$'\n\n\n\n\n'` and then do `<ESC>@l` and it will enter 5 newlines for you. They can also be used recursively - and can even swap command/edit modes w/ `<ESC>`.

Comment: @mikeserv ah. Gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options that spring to mind

1. Spacer lines:

   ```
   sl() { yes '' | head -"${1:-5}"; }    # Use as "sl 10" or "sl"
   ```
2. Pipe the output of your make through a pager:

   ```
   make {whatever} 2>&1 | less
   ```
3. Run the entire session under `screen`. You can then <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> and scroll up through the buffer a page at a time using <kbd>Ctrl B</kbd>. Use <kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to exit scrollback mode

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little C program to print three lines of bricks across the terminal for this purpose.  Not empty space, but it helps give visual separation in the same way, and stands out in verbose output that might have a bunch of vertical space.  Swap out your favorite character to taste:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct winsize ws;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);

    int i=0;
    // square:       \u25A0
    // large square: \u2B1B
    // block:        \u2588
    for(;i<3*ws.ws_col;++i) printf("\u2588");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have

```
alias five='echo -e "\n\n\n\n"'
```

for that, you can further shorten the alias to your liking of course.

Comment: This is similar to the comment from @Lambert. I do like the use of the word "five" here though. I'd more likely use "twenty" or "thirty", but I do get your point. My response to @Lambert was that I hoped this may already exist. The number of lines could be an environment variable; with a default value. Shall we call it `space`?

Comment: I didn't see Lamberts comment, as it is part of the show X more comments under your question. The name should be short, otherwise typing is to cumbersome, I chose 5 lines as I wanted to have the visual break when scrolling back in the terminal.

Comment: It would be nice to bind Ctrl+L to do that command within the terminal, but I never found out how. The other drawback I cannot use it in long running proceseses (or in tail -f) to generate some visual separation, like I can with pressing return a couple of times.

Comment: It seems to do it already for me. I'm using gnome terminal on Ubuntu. @mikeserv put this in the comments.

Comment: @Anthon; you might have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36922/keyboard-shortcut-to-send-text-strings-to-program where you should be able to use `xdotool` or `xvkdb` to print some text to an program and you should be able to set a global hotkey to run the tool. Did not get that to work properly so the CTRL+L is the best choice for this particular question.

Comment: @user7543 I can do Ctrl+L but it clears the screen I want it to do a formfeed by inserting newlines, like on the Teletype in the good old '80s

Comment: @Anthon I don't know about that, but I'm delighted with CTRL+l; hadn't previously noticed that it does still keep the rest of your session text. I can see it using CTRL+SHIFT+UP, or my mouse wheel.

Comment: @Anthon - try to set it to the terminal esc: `\033[?S` where `?` is some number of lines you want to scroll forward. It should work - it's ANSI, I think. It's what `tput` does with `indn` if you like that better.

Answer (score 1):

I trust you already have enough ways to abbreviate `echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n\n"`, so I won't add to that. But you have another option: **Many terminal emulators support searching,** so you can go to the start of the last command by searching backwards for some part of your prompt. (Or for some known string in the output, but the prompt is always there.)

TBH I usually just do the same thing you've been doing-- my Return key repeats fast enough that it never bothered me much to just hold it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`clear`** multiple times (`clear;clear`) or just hold down  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> *until you satisfy!*

With [`zsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), you can try (fun with `repeat`):-

- `repeat 5 clear`
- `repeat 20 echo`
- `repeat 50 printf '\n'`

And of-course you may want to `alias goaway='repeat 7 clear'`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to have some unique text in your prompt (I use `$` followed by a non-breaking space (`PS1=$'$\ua0'`)).

And configure your terminal emulator to scroll-back to it upon some key press.

For instance, with GNU `screen`, in `~/.screenrc`:

```
defscrollback 5000
bindkey \033` eval copy "stuff k?$\240\r"
```

Would map that to <kbd>Alt+Backtick</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`bash` script to print a custom number of newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    for ((i=0; i<$1; i++))
    do
        echo
    done
    exit 0
fi
exit 1
```

Name it (say `script.bash`) and put it in your `$PATH` (say in `/usr/bin`), run `chmod +x /usr/bin/script.bash` and call it with `script.bash <number_of_lines>`, or put it wherever you want, mark it as executable and add an alias to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias script.bash='bash /path/to/script'
```

You can change / shorten the name and the alias to your needs. It can also be modified to print a default number of lines if no argument is passed:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    $1=5
fi
for ((i=0; i<$1; i++))
do
    echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a sideways answer to your question, but I prefer using an inverted prompt (which stands out and is easy to spot) for just the purpose of quickly being able to determine where in the scrollback the last command was run.

You can invert your prompt's color (i.e. black text on white background) by adding the ANSI sequences `<esc>[7m` (invert) to the beginning of the prompt, and `<esc>[0m` (reset) to the end of it.

Most, more fancy shells (like `bash` and `zsh`) also keep track of the length of the prompt on screen, so you'll need to add some sugar to tell the shell that these sequences do not move the cursor forward. In `zsh` this is done using `%{...%}` while `bash` uses `\[...\]`.

Thus, to invert your prompt in `zsh` use:

```
PROMPT=$'%{\e[7m%}'"${PROMPT% }"$'%{\e[0m%} '
```

and in `bash`, use:

```
PS1=$'\[\e[7m%\]'"${PS1% }"$'\[\e[0m\] '
```

`$'...'` is a special way of quoting a string, which will translate `\e` into `<esc>`

`${VARNAME%SUFFIX}` removes outputs `VARNAME`, but strips off any ending string `SUFFIX` (in the above cases the final space, since we don't want to invert that in order to see the cursor properly).

---

Occasionally I find that the above trick is impractical (typically when the need arise to look at some logfile or something on a server which isn't really mine to customize to death), but on those occasions I usually find that all of the above suggested solutions are also too much of an effort, and I just press `<enter>` for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just `clear` twice! Example:

```
clear; clear; echo "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash I find CTRL+l moves the cursor to the top of the screen, but CTRL+L (i.e. CTRL+SHIFT+l) moves the cursor to the top of the screen, *and* inserts around a screen of space beforehand. Ideal! Thanks @Anthon.