# How do I go to the last line where I entered text in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I often use tmux to scroll through error messages for various reasons.

Usually I use the `ninja` command to build my projects so when I hit compilation errors `ctrl+b` `[` `ninja` quickly takes me back to where I ran the command.

However, today I started using `make` because, for various reasons, I couldn't use `ninja`. Because the string `make` appears multiple times in my build errors, this little trick no longer works.

So how can I get tmux to take me back to the last line on which I entered text (or where I last pressed return)?

Comment: [add something specific in your shell prompt like some special character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210291)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas great idea, thanks! If you post this as the answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I've given  a `screen` answer over there, I'll let you give the `tmux` one here. I'm not familiar with `tmux` having been a `screen` user for decades.